# French translation of "Bagging" in the case of Artificial Intelligence

Tags: traduction, anglais

I'm studying Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning and I would like to translate into French the technical term "Bagging" also known as "Bootstrap Agregating" defined in the following wikipedia page :
[Bootstrap Agregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating). My goal is to write this term in a French scientific paper.

J'étudie l'Intelligence Artificielle et l'Apprentissage Automatique et j'aimerais traduire en français le mot technique "Bagging" aussi connu sous le nom de "Bootstrap Agregating" défini sur la page wikipédia suivante : [Bootstrap Agregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating). L'objectif de cette traduction est de pouvoir en parler dans un papier scientifique en français.

EDIT :

I'm specifically looking for a translation because in my paper, I list the different methods I compare with their French translation as following :

- Linear Discriminant Analysis, Analyse Discriminante Linéaire
- Trees, Arbres de Décisions
- Naive Bayes, Modèle de Bayes Naif
- Generalized Linear Model, Modèle Linéaire Généralisé
- Random Forest, Forêt Aléatoires
- **Bootstrap Agregating, Bagging, ???????**

And my translation for Bagging is empty.

Comment: Ton papier, il cause de quoi ? de librairies, méthodes, fonctions logicielles? ou c'est une étude théorique sur l'*agrégation* ? Il cause aussi de *boosting* et de *random forest* ou non ? Il est destiné a être publié dans quoi ?

Comment: @aCOSwt C'est plus un rapport qu'un papier, un rapport dans le cadre scolaire car j'étudie la science des données. Il applique plusieurs méthodes de classification dont le _bootstrap agregating_ à un problème, et donc une base de données, particulier. Parmi ces méthodes, il y a en effet les _forêts aléatoires, random forest_

Comment: Bonjour, est-ce relié à [ceci](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529034) ou [ceci](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529040) ? Merci.

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme, oui c'est relié à ceci pour la partie _Bootstrap_ que j'essaie de définir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DANS LE CADRE PRÉCISÉ EN COMMENTAIRES DANS L'OP :

***Bagging*** en particulier : Je ne m'amuserais en aucun cas à traduire ce terme en français pour deux raisons :

- D'abord parce qu'il s'agit d'un acronyme et que les acronymes on ne les traduit pas,
- Ensuite parce que, dans cet acronyme, apparaît un terme très éloquent pour tous les acteurs de l'IR depuis 50 ans (soit bien avant 90 et des) : BAG! Comme dans *bag of words* que l'on a traduit par *sac de mots*.
  La traduction française de *bagging* imposerait donc logiquement que les trois lettres S,A,C puissent apparaître consécutivement, on attendra un chercheur désœuvré pour... trouver. ;-)

*Bootstrap agregating* : Tu sais que **bootstrap** est ici employé dans son sens statistique. Dans ce sens, nombreux sont ceux qui ne le traduisent pas.
Si on veut à tout prix, alors le terme de ***ré-échantillonnage*** me semble le mieux convenir avec, je trouve, le gros défaut d'être plus général quand le *bootstrap* désigne un type particulier de ré-échantillonnage.
Si on veut être précis en utilisant ré-échantillonnage, il faudra alors recourir à une périphrase, que je trouverais un peu lourdingue dans le cadre d'un rapport technique.
Je ne traduirais donc pas non plus ce *bootstrap*.

Tu réalises alors que périphrase + agrégation... Bref, je ne traduirais pas non plus, mais, si tu parles d'*agrégation* dans ta partie consacrée aux *forêts*, autant rester cohérent et préférer : *agrégation bootstrap*

EDIT : Ha! bien évidemment... tu me balances tout ça en... italiques.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse @aCOSwt, je mets +1 à ta réponse, un dernier point avant de choisir ta réponse comme celle qui répond à ma problématique, j'ai édité ma question avec une précision sur pourquoi je cherche une traduction. Peux-tu me confirmer qu'il n'est, dans ce cas précis, toujours pas recommandé de traduire en français Bootstrap Agregating ou Bagging ? Et de laisser tel quel en anglais ?

Comment: @J.Khamphousone : OK! Tu cherches absolument à traduire, je peux comprendre. Bon! Mais même dans ce cas, je garde *bagging* inchangé pour la seule raison qu'il s'agit d'un acronyme et qu'un acronyme, cela ne se traduit jamais. Suite dans comm suivant...

Comment: @J.Khamphousone :  Pour *bootstrap agregating*, libre à toi. Mais, comme je l'indique ci-contre, il va falloir recourir à une périphrase. Même en reprenant la suggestion de *nonobstant_fascisme* en commentaires dans l'OP. Car en admettant *autoamorçage* pour *bootstrap*, on ne peut pas aller directement à *agrégation autoamorcée* qui n'aurait ici aucun sens puisque formellement il s'agit d'une *agrégation d'échantillons générés par une méthode d'autoamorçage*.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a quick research. In most papers, it is used as bagging, directly.

But if you really want a translation, here is a paper that I found: https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/124833/1/CAP2012.pdf ( Look for page 2, last paragraph). It is used as **agrégation bootstrap**.

But as I said, it is just fine to use bagging (le bagging).

Comment: Welcome to French StackExchange ! Thank you for your answer, the link you post doesn't seem to work, can you check if it's still correct please ?

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the link. Look for the last paragraph on page 2.

Comment: thank you, I +1 your answer ;)

Comment: De rien, bon courage!